# Query to many-to-many joiner table in EDMX

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am currently facing performance problem whenever I'm accessing navigation property of an entity.

I have three tables: `UserCategory`,`User` and `UserCategoryUser`. There is **many-to-many** relation between `User` and `UserCategory` tables. `UserCategoryUser` table is the joiner table and it has two columns *UserId* and *UserCategoryId* i.e the primary keys of `User` and `UserCategory` tables. The joiner table `UserCategoryUser` is used for maintaining the many-to-many relationship between `User` and `UserCategory` tables.

I'm using database first approach. Hence in my EDMX, for the `User` entity I have one navigation property `UserCategories`. Similarly for the `UserCategory` entity there is a navigation property `Users`.

I want to add a user to a usercategory. So before adding, I'm doing a check whether the user is already added to the usercategory or not. In my database I've around **100k** user records and only one usercategory. All the users associated with the only usercategory.

I'm accessing the `Users` navigation property like follows:

```
var userCategory = Context.UserCategories.FirstOrDefault(uc => uc.UserCategoryId == userCategoryId);

if (userCategory != null)
{
    if (userCategory.Users.Any(u => u.Username == username))
    {
        //Other operations
    }
}
```

This code was working before but now it is hanging as we have lots of user data. 
In particular it is hanging for `userCategory.Users.Any(u => u.Username == username))` line. I also tried getting the users `count` but still it is hanging!

```
userCategory.Users.Count();
```

I'm not able to do the join query in LINQ to Entity as the joiner table(`UserCategoryUser`) is NOT added as an entity in the EDMX.

How to solve this problem? I can to this check using pure SQL or stored procedure but I want to stay away from those for this case.

Comment: are you loading all userCategory.Users  into memory ?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm querying like:
userCategory.Users.Any(u => u.Username == username)

Comment: Debug it and tell me how many items are in Users

Comment: I'm not getting the count. It is returning "function evaluation timeout". I assume it is loading all data to memory. I checked from the Context object that the lazyloading  is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that with lazy loading enabled, the call to `userCategory.Users` loads all Users into memory. I think, given that there are very few categories, I would do it the other way round. i.e. get the User then check whether the user's Category collection contains the category being added.

However, if you had a very large number of categories then you could explicitly filter the collection. First turn off lazy loading on the collection (e.g. by removing the `virtual` keyword), then try this:

```
   Context.Entry(userCategory)
              .Collection(uc => uc.Users)
              .Query()
              .Where(u => u.Username == username)//I'd put an index on username too
              .Load();

   if(userCategory.Users.Any())
   {
      //Other operations
   }
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicitFilter

Comment: Correct, or call `Context.UserCategories.Where(uc => uc.UserCategoryId == userCategoryId && uc.Users.Any(u => u.Username == username))`

Comment: @Gert and that is a much better way to do it! Not just because it runs one query to the database, but because it is far more obvious what you are doing. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Is there any other way how I can improve the performance without turning OFF the lazy loading(having no idea about how many row entries will be there for the navigation property)?

Comment: Yes.  Get the User then check whether the user's Category collection contains the category being added. Or call `Context.UserCategories.Where(uc => uc.UserCategoryId == userCategoryId && uc.Users.Any(u => u.Username == username))`

Comment: Whenever a user is added it will hang. Like:
userCategory.Users.Add(new User());  Same is for remove.
How to handle this case?